# How to correctly deploy Blazor WebAssembly (hosted) app?

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I am following instructions on how to  deploy Blazor WebAssembly (HOSTED) as stated here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

It is unclear when I want to publish project do I run publish on a WebAssembly project or on Server project. Both projects under same solution do allow publish and publish directories are created separately, for example

> /bin/Release/netstandard2.1/publish

and

> /bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish

Which directory out of these two should I deploy to production server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Publish the server. It contains the app.

Comment: That is what I am doing, just wanted to make sure that is the only proper way to do it.