# Deploying Blazor WebAssembly & Blazor Server (Blazor Hosted) to AWS Amplify

Tags: deployment, aws-amplify, release, blazor-webassembly, hosted-blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to deploy my app to AWS Amplify that's using Microsoft's template for .net7. Since I'm using Authenication/Authorization and local UserAccounts has a Blazor WebAssembly (Client), Blazor Server (.Net Core) and a shared project (contains Models) all under a single solution file. Most of the examples I've looked have the amplify.yml setup to deploy a client side Blazor app, I need to deploy the entire solution.

Here's my yml and my questions I'm running into

Q1 - In the examples, it has the build command "./dotnet7/dotnet publish -c Release -o release" that sends it into a top level release folder. But since there's a solution instead of a single project when the command runs there's a warning that its not support/recommend to do for a solution. So I'm building the solution and then setting the frontend to use the backend wwwroot folder. (I've also tried to have the section be backend and reference the backend server)

Q2 - I don't think I need to have two sections backend and frontend in the yml, lookin at [How to correctly deploy Blazor WebAssembly (hosted) app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61634354/how-to-correctly-deploy-blazor-webassembly-hosted-app) it looks like only the backend needs to be hosted/published.

Q3 - I'm using code first for EF. Where's the best place to apply the migrations, postBuild and run the command "./dotnet7/dotnet update-database" ? (I'm sure that once I get the app running I'd be good)

```
version: 1
frontend:
    phases:
        preBuild:
            commands:
            - curl -sSL https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh > dotnet-install.sh
            - chmod +x *.sh
            - ./dotnet-install.sh -c 7.0 -InstallDir ./dotnet7
            - ./dotnet7/dotnet --version
        build:
            commands:
            - ./dotnet7/dotnet publish -c Release
    artifacts:
        baseDirectory: /Server/bin/Release/net7.0/publish/wwwroot
        files:
            - '**/*'
    cache:
        paths: []
```